# Get Images to Login form before authentication in Jsp

Tags: jsp, web.xml

I want to design my login.jsp page. and when i put an image into it it doesnt show up.
i try to this before authentication.
the following code is in the web.xml file

```
  <security-constraint>
      <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>HtmlAdaptor</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
      </web-resource-collection>
      <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>TestRoleOne</role-name>
      </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
    <login-config>
      <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
      <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/login.jsp</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/error.jsp</form-error-page>
      </form-login-config>
    </login-config>
    <security-role>
        <role-name>TestRoleOne</role-name>
    </security-role>
    </web-app>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause is that access to everything, besides the login form is restricted by this element:

```
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
```

I can think of 2 ways to achieve what you want; first is untested but should work according to specs; second will work, but will require restructuring your files.

#### First way: Untested, modification only to web.xml

Sevlet 3, par. 13.8.1 says:

> A security constraint that does not contain an authorization constraint shall combine with authorization constraints that name or imply roles to allow unauthenticated access.

So add this to your web.xml (I assume the image location is `/login-image.png`, change as necessary):

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Login Image</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/login-image.png</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <!-- NO auth-constraint ELEMENT AT ALL -->
</security-constraint>
```

#### Second way: restructure your app

You can separate the protected and unprotected folders in your application (don't forget any servlet names), e.g. directory structure:

```
+- protected
|  |
|  +- (protected stuff)
|
+- unprotected
|  |
|  +- (unprotected stuff)
|
+- WEB-INF
   |
   +- (etc)
```

And then modify web.xml:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>HtmlAdaptor</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/protected/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    ...
</security-constraint>
```